# How to debug a GPF crash?

Tags: vb6, crash, crash-dumps

I have an old VB6 app that uses a lot of 3rd party components, not just visual but also for audio processing, tcp/udp, VoIP, etc...

When I run the app as an EXE (e.g. not in the VB6 IDE), it will crash sometimes with a GPF.  It happens after the program has been running for several days and occurs when there is no one around.

Unfortunately the user has clipped the screenshot, but it typically doesn't have any useful information anyway.  The description of the crash reported that the crash occurred in `ntdll.dll`.

[image]

My questions:

1. What tools do I need in order to debug this?
2. How do I actually get started?
3. I have the PDB files from the compilation in VB6. The app is compiled to `Optimize for Fast Code`. What can I do with them in this situation?

Comment: Use logging to find out which part of the code causes the crash?

Comment: @MarkJ The error is not being caught anywhere in my code.  It must be happening in either the runtime or 3rd party controls.

Answer (score 2):

I would use ntsd or windbg ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg463009/)), and run the app under either of the user mode debuggers (if you're not familiar, they have the same commands - ntsd is a console debugger, while windbg is a GUI debugger). Both have a lot of command line options, but ntsd appname.exe will be enough to get started. Use the .sympath command to point the debugger toward the symbol, and you should be on your way. When the crash occurs, you can examine variables and stack in order to figure out what may be missing.

BTW - the error above is an invalid handle error, so the program probably passed a stale or NULL handle to a windows function. The debugger will tell you more.